# PayPal REST API /v1/reporting/balances balance_detail returning wrong negative balance

Tags: api, rest, paypal

Good morning,
I'm trying to add a feature to my application  which will display the current PayPal account balance. I use to PayPal REST API to get transaction details, so thought it would be easy enough to use it to get the balance too. I am trying to use the /balances resource as described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/#definition-balance_detail)

I can successfully make the call and get a valid response. However, the balance is wrong, currently showing a negative balance when it is positive. The actual code I am using is (in Windows):

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/balances?currency_code=GBP&as_of_time=2020-04-02T10:07:00-1007" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>"
```

(I replace  with my access token)
Does anyone know why this is happening? I notice that the "as_of_time" in the response is 3 hours earlier than the time in the request I make, so maybe the URL should include the time of a different time zone. Regardless of this, our balance was never negative. The same result is obtained if I omit the "as_of_time".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already know the answer, `transaction search` always has a delay because the interface is not real-time.